# How to limit one loop's iteration in nested for loop?

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop, scripting

I am a beginner in python and trying to create 100 files with some random data written to it. For this i have created a nested for loop

```
file_size=['10','20','50','100','500']

for i in range(100):
        j="abcd1234:"+(format(i, '03d'))
        <action to create file>
        for size in file_size:
                cmd_write_data = 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/' + j + ' bs=1M' + ' count=' + size
                print (cmd_write_data)
```

Output is like

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:000 bs=1M count=10
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:000 bs=1M count=20
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:000 bs=1M count=50
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:000 bs=1M count=100
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:000 bs=1M count=500
.
.
.
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:099 bs=1M count=10
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:099 bs=1M count=20
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:099 bs=1M count=50
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:099 bs=1M count=100
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:099 bs=1M count=500
```

but i expected to set size once to one file

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:000 bs=1M count=10
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:001 bs=1M count=20
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:002 bs=1M count=50
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:003 bs=1M count=100
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:004 bs=1M count=500
```

and so on till end of file range. Please share your thoughts on how to limit one loop iteration in a nested for loop. Thanks in advance.
P.S Working with Python 2.7

Comment: and what should go here: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:005 bs=1M count=?` `10` again?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be iterating from 0 to 100; you should be iterating through the file sizes, and update `i` in there:

```
i = 0
for size in file_size:
    j="abcd1234:"+(format(i, '03d'))
    cmd_write_data = 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/' + j + ' bs=1M' + ' count=' + size
    print (cmd_write_data)
    i += 1
```

As strubbly pointed out, there is even a built-in function that can keep track of an index while iterating: `enumerate()`.

```
for i, size in enumerate(file_size):
    j = "abcd1234:" + format(i, '03d')
    cmd_write_data = 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/' + j + ' bs=1M' + ' count=' + size
    print(cmd_write_data)
```

Comment: Better still `for i,size in enumerate(file_size):`

Comment: @zondo @strubbly, I have tried with both loop that you have suggested. Now different file_size can be assigned to each file but loops end when file_size list ends with 5 iterations. I intend to create more number of files (say 100)
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:000 bs=1M count=10dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:001 bs=1M count=20
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:002 bs=1M count=50
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:003 bs=1M count=100
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:004 bs=1M count=500
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/mydir/abcd1234:005 bs=1M count=1000`

Comment: @Satz: Your `count` pattern does not seem to be something a program could calculate. If you need more numbers, add more things to `size`.